# fail to insert into two tables via stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert into two tables at the same time via stored procedure but it writes to only one table and fail to the other.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_emp_pics]
@EmpName nvarchar(100), 
@Nationality nvarchar(30), 
@PassportPic nvarchar(100), 
@Pic nvarchar(100)
AS
Begin
set nocount on;
DECLARE @ID int, 
@Emp_ID int
insert into Employee (EmpName,Nationality)
values (@EmpName,@Nationality)
select @ID = @@IDENTITY
insert into DatePics 
(PassportPic,Pic)
values
(@PassportPic ,@Pic)
select @Emp_ID  = @@IDENTITY
 end
```

There is relation between two tables

**first table** `[Employee]` `PK ID`

**second table** `[DatePics]` `FK Emp_ID`

this is the error message after executing this statement.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Emp_ID', table 'QTecTest.dbo.DatePics'; 
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Comment: Your `Emp_ID` column isn't an identity. Therefore SQL expects you to supply a value for it during inserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert the new `Emp_Id` as a Foreign Key to `DatePics` (and assuming both tables have identity columns):

```
insert into Employee (EmpName,Nationality)
values (@EmpName,@Nationality);
set @EMP_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
insert into DatePics (PassportPic,Pic, Emp_ID)
values (@PassportPic ,@Pic, @EmpID);
set @DatePicsID  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Also, please use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` over `@@IDENTITY` - `@@Identity` is vulnerable to issues where a Trigger also creates an new (unrelated) identity.

Comment: if I inserted the Emp_id as a new FK, then I must declare it while I write my C# statement. The Emp_ID suppose to be auto generated form ID. How to put the value of the auto generated [ID] at [Emp_ID] ?
Thanks

Comment: After you insert the Employee record, a new Employee ID PK will be created by SQL. `SET @Emp_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` will grab the newly inserted `Employee.Emp_Id` and use this to populate the dependent foreign key `Emp_ID` on the `DatePics` table. You can return both the identities `@Emp_ID` and `@DatePicsID` back to your C# Code, e.g. `SELECT` them at the end of the PROC and then bind the result with a `DataReader`, or return both as OUTPUT parameters?

Answer (score 1):

A column declared as primary key cannot have NULL values. 
In your stored procedure you are not supplying value to `Emp_ID` column and so Insert fails.
If you want to automatically insert values in that column make it as [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) column also